# Encrypted Application not running on one machine

Tags: .net, obfuscation, net-reactor

I use Eziriz .Net Reactor to protect our dlls and exes from reverse engineering. It has been working fine for years.

Just today, on one single machine, the protected application stopped running. It is exactly the same file versions as what previously ran, and the exact same files work on several other machines.

I can't understand what might have gone wrong on this one machine. All other software works fine on it. The same application code works if it isn't protected, but fails if it is protected. There are no errors shown. I simply try to run the exe, the process starts and then shuts down again.

The only thing different about this machine, is that I have recently been installing and uninstalling lots of 3rd party software. Does .Net Reactor rely on some system settings, registry settings, etc which may have become corrupted?

If I have to, I will wipe the machine and reinstall windows - but I'd prefer not to. I'd also like to understand what has gone wrong.

Comment: Further investigation shows that the issue is with the "necrobit" setting. If I turn that option off, the protected application works on the problem machine. Weird - necrobit always worked before.

Comment: Have you contacted Eziriz about this?

Comment: Yes, but they couldn't offer an explanation. In the end, I reinstalled Windows and its all working again now.

Comment: This has happened again on a different machine and with a different one of our products. This time the machine was XP and the only unusual thing was it was still running Office 2003. Turning off necrobit fixed it. We noticed that update KB2726929 installed around the time our protected software stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's been a long time since this question about .Net Reactor, I want to share my experience to help other people.
I had the same problem and in my case it was the "FIPS" (Federal Information Processing Standards) option that was enabled in Windows.
The .Net Reactor version used during this discovery was 6.0.0.0 and similarly, when I disable the "NecroBit" option it works perfectly.
There seems to be a conflict between FIPS and NecroBit when both are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter similar issues with **Eziriz Rector** and **Intellilock** recently when I received Windows update including 3rd party software updates.

I have to "protect" my application by de-selecting all protection options, then adding each option back one after another to find out which is causing problems with other software. For example, just last month one option causes the application to be recognized as a "mal-ware" by Avira after the antivirus software get updated.

I think the bigger problem is we have no idea what 3rd party software the clients have on their machine, and yet I have to programmatically find out the compatibility issue before installation of the distribution. Perhaps someone has better ideas.

Comment: I would be interested to know which protection option caused the issue. Also - do you protect the application exe, or just important dlls, or both?

Comment: if I remember correctly is suppress ILDASM. We'll be publishing another application, I'll post more detail by then